# Intervention\Image\Exception\NotSupportedException Encoding format (tmp) is not supported

Tags: laravel, intervention

I am using the Intervention package with Laravel 5.6, the issue I am getting whenever I am uploading a file I have been presented with the error Encoding format(tmp) is not supported. I have my gdd2 extension enabled also. This is the code where I have used.

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request , [
            'name'          => 'required|unique:categories',
            'description'   =>  'max:355',
            'image'         =>  'required|image|mimes:jpeg,bmp,png,jpg'
        ]);

        // Get Form Image
        $image = $request->file('image');
        $slug = str_slug($request->name);
        if (isset($image))
        {
            $currentDate = Carbon::now()->toDateString();
            $imageName = $slug.'-'.$currentDate.'-'.uniqid().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            // Check if Category Dir exists
            if (!Storage::disk('public')->exists('category'))
            {
                Storage::disk('public')->makeDirectory('category');
            }
            // Resize image for category and upload
            $categoryImage = Image::make($image)->resize(1600,479)->save();
            Storage::disk('public')->put('category/'.$imageName, $categoryImage);

            // Check if Category Slider Dir exists
            if (!Storage::disk('public')->exists('category/slider'))
            {
                Storage::disk('public')->makeDirectory('category/slider');
            }

            // Resize image for category slider and upload
            $categorySlider = Image::make($image)->resize(500,333)->save();
            Storage::disk('public')->put('category/slider/'.$imageName, $categorySlider);

        }
        else
        {
            $imageName = 'default.png';
        }

        $category = new Category();
        $category->name = $request->name;
        $category->slug = $slug;
        $category->description = $request->description;
        $category->image = $imageName;

        $category->save();
        Toastr::success('Category Saved Successfully','Success');
        return redirect()->route('admin.category.index');
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Intervention image **save()** method requires a filename so it knows what file format (jpg, png, etc..) to save your image in.

The reason you are getting the error is it does not know what encoding to save the temporary image object ***(tmp)*** in.

Here is an example

```
->save('my-image.jpg', 90)
```

There is also a optional second parameter that controls the quality output. The above outputs at 90% quality.

http://image.intervention.io/api/save

Answer (score 8):

You don't need to use the save() function on the `Intervention\Image` class as you are saving the file to your public disc via the `Storage` Facade.

Simply replace the line

`$categoryImage = Image::make($image)->resize(1600,479)->save();`

with

`$categoryImage = Image::make($image)->resize(1600,479)->stream();`

to avoid having to store the image to the temp folder under a .tmp extension. Laravel `Storage` Facade will handle the stream created by `Intervention\Image` and store the file to the public disk.

Answer (score 0):

Saw this somewhere and it worked for me

```
$image->save('foo' . $img->getClientOriginalExtension());
```

Answer (score 0):

The Laravel Intervention image save() method requires a filename so it knows what file format (jpg, png, etc..) to save your image in

```
 $categoryImage = Image::make($image)->resize(1600,479)->save( $imageName,90);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this by

> Trimming
>   my file path, i was using this script inside laravel **Artisan Console**.

```
$img->save(trim('public/uploads/images/thumbnails/'.$subFolder.'/'.$filename));
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather you use stream its working without error

```
$categoryImage = Image::make($image)->resize(1600,479)->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

1. $categoryImage = Image::make($image)->resize(1600,479)->save();
   Storage::disk('public')->put('category/'.$imageName, $categoryImage);

change to

```
Image::make($image)->resize(1600, 479)->save(storage_path('app/public/category').'/'.$imagename);
```

2. 

```
$categorySlider = Image::make($image)->resize(500,333)->save();
Storage::disk('public')->put('category/slider/'.$imageName, $categorySlider);
```

change to

```
Image::make($image)->resize(500, 333)->save(storage_path('app/public/category/slider/') .$imagename);
```